# Block SSH connection from my server to another server

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, nginx, amazon-ec2

I have gotten an Email from AWS that my instance has been used to attach other servers through SSh method. I just want to know how I can stop sshing other servers from my server so that these kinds of attacks can be blocked.

Hello Abuse-Team,

your Server/Customer with the IP: *x.x.x.x* (ec2-x-x-x-x.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com) has attacked one of our servers/partners.
The attackers used the method/service: *ssh* on: *Fri, 16 Dec 2022 13:52:36 +0100*.
The time listed is from the server-time of the Blocklist-user who submitted the report.
The attack was reported to the Blocklist.de-System on: *Fri, 16 Dec 2022 13:52:39 +0100*

I tried blocking outbound rules to ssh but that sort of setting is not available in AWS as yet.

Comment: The more important issue is that your instance has been compromized and should be terminated. But anway, you can use Netwrok ACL rules to DENY ssh outgoing connections.

Comment: How can I do that? What changes should I make in the outbound rule?

Answer (score 0):

you need to edit the security group, which is attached to your ec2 instance,
check for inbound rules and edit rules related to port 22/TCP.